# Showing/Managing a list of files/directories in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, algorithm, oop, list

I'm looking for a way to show a list of directories and files in them using javascript. The kind of structure I want is:

- Directory 1

  - File 1

    - Path
    - Action taken (deleted, added, modified)
  - File 2

    - Path
    - Action taken (deleted, added, modified)
- Directory 2

  - File 1

    - Path
    - Action taken (deleted, added, modified)
  - File 2

    - Path
    - Action taken (deleted, added, modified)
  - Sub Directory 1

    - Subdirectory File 1

      - Path
      - Action taken (deleted, added, modified)
    - Subdirectory File 2

      - Path
      - Action taken (deleted, added, modified)

etc. What I'm looking for is:

1) How to loop through all the items that I have.

2) How to display them in a tree.

3) How to easily get a list of all children of a parent, for selecting/deselecting. (E.g if user clicks the name 'Directory 1', then all children of that directory (files, subdirectories, subdirectory files etc) will have the checkbox next to them selected/unselected.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm yet to find a nice js tree implementation.

[jsTree](http://www.jstree.com/) is strong enough to build off it the functionality you want, although I find it very unintuitive and hard to use and customise. There is a reasonably active message board which can help. The author has been promising a rewrite for about a year, and [posted](http://groups.google.com/group/jstree/browse_thread/thread/711f471181f4fb16) that there will be commits coming soon, although if you look at the message board history he's been saying that for like 6 months, at least.

I haven't found anything better than jsTree, and I don't really like it, so I wish you luck.

I think a tree widget is [on the wishlist](http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12138128/Tree) for jqueryui, but don't hold your breath. [This](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-tree/) is supposed to be the repo I think.

<del>And there's [this](https://github.com/astashov/jquery-ui-tree). No idea if it's any good, just found it when I was looking for the jqueryui links.</del> (Looks like there haven't been commits since 2009, probably not the best idea to pick it up then...)

If you find something nice, please post it.

Comment: I haven't found anything, I'm ending up writing my own. I wasn't looking for a javascript tree object per se, rather I wanted ideas on what kind of algorithm to use for maintaining them in a tree list, getting all files/directories in a parent directory, etc..

Comment: @Click, for an in-memory tree implementation there are no special algorithms you need to know - as long as you're comfortable with basic tree traversal and objects in js you should be able to create the required Node type with very little effort and all the basic functionality

Comment: That's true, however the issue here is, every node can be either a: directory array containing subdirs/files of the dir, or a directory Object, indicating that the directory itself was changed, i.e added or deleted. Perhaps I need to refactor it somehow to always use an object, however that creates the issue of how to loop through the files/subdirs of a directory..

Comment: @Click, don't see the problem, you have two types, File and Directory, which each have a parent pointer, and an action flag. Directory in addition has children in an array. The array elements can themselves be Directories or Files. When you add/delete/change any element you flag it appropriately, and follow the parent pointers up to the root flagging 'modified' as you go. What's the big deal?

Comment: You're right.. thanks.. its hard to explain what I was doing but your approach is much simpler, so I'll take that. Thanks :)